# How to check that git commits contain string pattern in message?

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I have a GitLab repository with some projects. I want to check that commits messages contain regex string pattern ('[0-9]{3}', for example) for someone who want to push he's commits to the project. If there is no string pattern in user's commit messages then return message "Your commit's message doesn't contain necessary string pattern" for that user.

I know that there is git hooks and I can write my own here: `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/awesome.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive` but how can I retrive user's commits messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pre-receive or update hook, you are given—on stdin, or as arguments—a *reference name*, the *old value* of the reference, and the *new value* of the reference.  The update hook gets one reference, as arguments.  You can make a single decision about the single reference update based on those three arguments: to allow it, or to prevent it.  The pre-receive hook gets *all* the proposed updates, one per line, on its standard input, and you must read *all* of standard input before making your one decision: to allow all of the proposed updates to pass through to the next step—which includes running the update hook, one name at a time—or to deny the update as a whole.

In all cases, each reference uses its full, spelled-out format.  Be sure to use all of it, so that you do not mistake *tag* `X`, `refs/tags/X`, for the different reference `refs/heads/X` that names *branch* `X`.  Similarly, do not confuse branch name `refs/heads/experiment/master` with `refs/heads/master`, which would happen if you simply stripped off everything up through (i.e., including) the final `/`.  You may even get a request to update a reference that is neither a branch name *nor* a tag name, such as a `refs/replace/` name-space item, or `refs/notes/commits`.

Similarly, the old value and new value are two complete Git hash IDs, except that exactly one—never both—may be the special all-zeros "null hash".  A null hash indicates that the reference is either being created (old value null, new value non-null) or destroyed (old value non-null, new value null).

#### Looking at commits

If you wish to look at all the incoming commits' messages, you must iterate over each commit in `$oldhash..$newhash`, except that you must handle "reference being created" or "reference being destroyed" differently.  When a reference is being created, it's sometimes impossible to know which commit(s), *if any* are coming in *because of* that new reference.  Consider for instance the case where your pre-receive hook gets:

```
012...789 aaa...aaa refs/heads/br1
345...eee 321...def refs/heads/br2
000...000 999...999 refs/tags/v2.1
```

Now, `refs/tags/v2.1` is being created (its old value is all-zeros).  Its new value is `999...`, which is presumably either an annotated tag object or a commit object.  But what if `999...` reaches a commit whose parent is `888...` *and* `888...` was not in the repository before?  Then the newly created tag is perhaps the source of commit `888...`.  On the other hand, the two branch names `br1` and `br2` are being changed as well.  What if one of them reaches `888...` as well?  (E.g., perhaps that's the grandparent commit of `aaa...`.)

The nearest you can get to "commits introduced by new reference" is to use `git rev-list <hash> --not --all` to get a list of commits reachable by the hash ID, that are not already reachable from all existing references.  That would count new commit `888...` as reachable from the tag, even if it's also *going to be* reachable from `br1` (provided you allow the update to `br1` of course).

For your case, this may be fine: if you reject the commit for having a bad message on `br1`, you can also reject the commit for having a bad message on `v1.2`, meaning you reject the commit twice, but so what?  Or it may *not* be fine, in which case, you must decide how you wish to handle it.  Just remember that your options are to read *all* updates in a pre-receive hook, and allow them all to proceed or reject them all; or to check *each update one at a time* in an update hook, and allow that one update to proceed, or to reject it.  In the pre-receive hook, since you have a global view of all updates, you can write fancy logic.  In an update hook, you have a narrow view, and you cannot write fancy logic: you must keep it simple.  Each has its advantages and disadvantages.

In any case, once you have an update, you can tell which commits will be reachable after the update that are not yet reachable:

```
git rev-list $newvalue ^$oldvalue | ...
```

and you can tell which commits were reachable from the old reference value that will no longer be reachable:

```
git rev-list $oldvalue ^$newvalue | ...
```

(the latter are commits that are being *removed* via force-push).  In the `...` section of the code, you can read each commit hash and do whatever you like with it, such as:

```
... | while read hash; do
    if git log --format=%B $hash | grep "$expr" >/dev/null; then
        # grep found a pattern in the body printed by %B
    else
        # grep did not find the pattern
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer with detailed explanations!